# Scss : different background on hover on different div

Tags: css, sass

I have a `div` with different images having different backgrounds. 
When I `hover` on it I should get the `background color` of respective image background.
i.e. If there is black background in the image then I should get the `overlay_div` background as black , if there is blue then I should get blue background overlay_div.

I am using scss to maintain the variable but I don't know how can I achieve?

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jo2uooyL/)

Any help would be great.

Comment: how are you planning to identify the image's background color? or do you know the colors of them?

Comment: yes. i know the colors of them. there are 5 different bg colors for each image

Comment: Why don't u use the transparent background, if you know the image colors?

Comment: I don't think it's possible directly. `SCSS` - no chance. Even using `Javascript/Jquery` it would be a mess. You need to know the color, you won't be able to do it by dynamically determining the image color

Comment: @VaibhavJain . I have contents on overlay div. that's why i can't use it.

Comment: @DeepakYadav , is there is any other solution for the same?

Comment: Then you need to use use javascript & create an array of objects which contains the image URL & the respective color & apply the background color accordingly. 

Something like this: 
[
{color: 'red', url: 'http://imagegur.com/red.jpeg'},
{color: 'blue', url: 'http://imagegur.com/blue.jpeg'},
{color: 'yellow', url: 'http://imagegur.com/yellow.jpeg'}
]

Comment: @Rishi. what i want to know is how do you detect which background image has which background color?

Comment: that's i don't know. i know the image background color and i can set the overlay background color div but i don't know how to set respective overlay div.

Comment: @VaibhavJain. yes using JS i can do that. I want to know if it is possible using only Scss?

Comment: I don't think using only SCSS would do that & even if there is a way it would be a mess.

Comment: ohkk.. thank you for that..

Comment: Best approach would be to have `css` `classes` for different colors you want, Once that specific color class is hovered, you show that color in background. This is good if there are few such classes. Not good if colors are to be dynamic or is a huge list.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood right, then you want to get the dominant color of the image and set it to the `overlay_div`, then, in this case, I recommend this plugin ...

[Colorify.js](http://colorify.rocks/)

But if you just going to have solid color images as background-image, then you just remove the `$black_bg_color;` altogether from the `overlay_div`